# Eiffel: type casting operators whats the difference between ~ / and attached statements?

Tags: eiffel

Whats the difference between

- object test

  ```
  if attached {DOG} an_animal as a_dog then
     a_dog.eat (meat)
  end
  ```
- operator `/` of the class `TYPE`

  ```
  if an_animal / a_dog then
     an_animal.eat (food)
  end
  ```
- reference equality `=`

  ```
  if a_dog = an_animal then
      a_dog.eat (meat)
  else
      an_animal.eat (food) 
  end
  ```
- object equality `~`

  ```
  if a_dog ~ an_animal then
      a_dog.eat (meat)
  else
      an_animal.eat (food) 
  end
  ```

And where can I find documentation about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main differences among the constructs are in operand types and semantics.

1. An object test allows for figuring out whether a particular expression evaluates to a value conforming to a particular type. The value of the conforming object can be retrieved via an associated object test local.
2. The operator `/` of the class `TYPE` returns the value of the passed argument, if it conforms to the type specified by the type object. Otherwise, it returns `Void` for a reference type and a default value for an expanded type. This is quite similar to object test, but has minor differences. Essentially, the expression `{SOME_TYPE} / expression` is equivalent to

   ```
   if attached {SOME_TYPE} expression as value then
       value
   else
       {detachable SOME_TYPE}.default
   end
   ```

   For reference types, the object test `attached {SOME_TYPE} expression as value` is equivalent to

   ```
   attached ({SOME_TYPE} / expression) as value
   ```

   But there is no equivalent for expanded types.

   The main use of the operator `/` is to obtain a value of a specific type if possible or `Void` otherwise:

   ```
   x := {SOME_TYPE} / expression
   ```
3. Reference equality `=` compares (most of the time) object references and has nothing to do with their types. In other words, `a = b` for reference objects means that `a` and `b` are aliases. If one of the operands is an expanded object, `=` is the same as object equality (see below).

   If the expression `dog = animal` returns `True`, the variables `dog` and `animal` reference the same object, but we have no idea what type it is.
4. Object equality `~` compares contents of two objects. First, it checks that both are non-void, have the same type, and then invokes a (user-defined) predicate `is_equal` to get the result of the operator.

   If the expression `dog ~ animal` returns `True`, the variables `dog` and `animal` could be the same or different objects that have the same type and are equal (according to `is_equal`). As in the previous case, we have no idea what type they are.

1, 3 and 4 are documented in the language standard, 2 is a feature of the class `TYPE` (with the corresponding name `attempted`).